# Argument of type 'typeof QuestionInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<QuestionInfo | undefined>'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

```
I am getting response from server and create model class of QuestionInfo type. then I am assigning that object into state array. Now I am getting object from array. Code is given below.

        const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<[QuestionInfo] | undefined>();
        const [questionObj, setQuestionObj] = useState<QuestionInfo | undefined>()
    
    
       useEffect(() => {
            testAPICall();
        }, []);
    
    //Method Call
    const testAPICall = async () => {
            try {`enter code here`
                const response = await fetch("URL",
                    {`enter code here`
                        method: "get",
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": "",
                        }
                    });
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log('Success :', json.data);
                setQuestions(json.data);
                setQuestionObj(questions[0])//This Line giving me error
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                console.log('error : ', error);
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting response from server is like

```
"data": [
        {
            "question": {
                "en": "What are the 3 most important parts of the &quot;18 Months&quot; rule?"
            },
            "options": {
                "en": [
                    "Product, service & traction",
                    "Working capital, customer base & strategy",
                    "Product, service & failure",
                    "Service, working capital & strategy"
                ]
            },
            "_id": "ZZZZZZZ",
            "question_type": "single"
        },
        {
            "question": {
                "en": "what is the most important thing he should keep in mind?"
            },
            "options": {
                "en": [
                    "Product specifications",
                    "Brand strategy",
                    "Customer's problems",
                    "Working capital"
                ]
            },
            "_id": "YYYYYYY",
            "question_type": "single"
        }
    ],
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

I am storing each object in QuestionInfo  object. if I am getting object for particular object. then. I am getting error

I am getting error like "Argument of type 'typeof QuestionInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<QuestionInfo | undefined>'".

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't set assign a QuestionInfo | undefined type to your state.

You have two solution.

1. Be sure that the object you are saving in your state is defined, for example:

```
if (questions[0]) {
    setQuestionObj(questions[0])
}
```

2. Add the undefined type on your state:

```
const [questionObj, setQuestionObj] = useState<QuestionInfo | undefined>(
```

Comment: I am still getting "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)" this error. on line 
            setQuestionObj(questions[0])

Comment: with which solution?

Comment: With this solution : const [questionObj, setQuestionObj] = useState<QuestionInfo | undefined>()

Comment: Can you post your whole component?

Comment: where I can post?. Comment box is taking too long char.

Comment: You are not typying the response, what type is response.json()? Why you are using pure javascript in the function and typescript on the state?